# Is there a way to tell angular $location not to discard array query parameters that come before the last one of the same name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, get, url-routing

When redirecting in AngularJS to a route such as

```
myapp.com/search/?someParam=someVal&someArrayParam[]=someArrayVal&someArrayParam[]=someArrayVal2
```

Angular will automatically discard `someArrayParam[]=someArrayVal` and leave only `someArrayParam[]=someArrayVal2` in the URL.

Is there a way to prevent this? I would much like to be able to send GET array values through routes for deeplinking complex interfaces. Right now the workaround I've come up with is to use $loc.url("/search/?filter="+JSON.stringify(scope.searchData)); but I'd much prefer the former.

Comment: When I last saw, this was a bug and was listed under issues in the github repo for angularjs. I still don't know if this has been solved. Check this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/750.

Comment: Thanks, +1d the issue, for what it's worth.